# Difference between copy functions in python

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, module

What is difference between copy.copy and copy.deepcopy functions in python?

```
>>> copy.deepcopy(li)
[1, 2, 3, 4]

>>> copy.copy(li)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

both does the same thing , can anyone tell what these functions does specifically

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> import copy
>>> L = [[1,2,3]]
>>> A = copy.copy(L)
>>> A[0].append(4)
>>> A
[[1, 2, 3, 4]]
>>> L
[[1, 2, 3, 4]]
>>> L = [[1,2,3]]
>>> A = copy.deepcopy(L)
>>> A[0].append(4)
>>> A
[[1, 2, 3, 4]]
>>> L
[[1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 3):

`copy.copy` performs a shallow copy as opposed to `copy.deepcopy` which performs a deep copy.

When considering:

```
li = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

you will not notice any difference, because you are copying immutable objects, however consider:

```
>>> import copy
>>> x = copy.copy(li)
>>> x
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> x[0][0] = 9
>>> li
[[9, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Since a shallow copy only makes copies of each reference in the list, manipulating these copied references will still affect the original list.

However the following code:

```
>>> x.append(1)
```

will have no effect on the original list.